# ContextMenuOpening event not firing in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a resource dictionary inside which I have a context menu:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyApp.Components.MyContextMenu"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
                    xmlns:components="clr-namespace:MyApp.Components">
    <ContextMenu ContextMenuOpening="OnContextMenuOpening">
```

and the resource dictionary XAML has this code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace MyApp.Components
{
    public partial class MyContextMenu : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public MyContextMenu()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }  

        void OnContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("here i am!");
        }
    }
}
```

The log is not appearing. I wonder why the event is not firing or getting to the right place -- is the problem because I have wrapped the context menu inside this resource dictionary?

**Update:** Interestingly if I remove the code-behind function, I get an error during compilation:

> does not contain a definition for 'ContextMenu_OnContextMenuOpening'
>   and no extension method 'ContextMenu_OnContextMenuOpening' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'MyApp.Components.MyContextMenu' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Update 2:** Looks like that both `Console.WriteLine` and `Debug.WriteLine` produce output, but only "randomly" and especially when I'm clicking near the bottom of the item. Some sort of collision detection not working maybe?

Comment: Where do you want to see the output of the `Console.WriteLine` in a WPF app? Change it to `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` and check in the output window.

Comment: @nemesv Tried. See my updated question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a bug in the framework: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/353112/contextmenu-opening-event-doesnt-fire-properly

> A contextmenu's opening event doesn't fire on the first right click.
>   It only fires when you do two sequential right clicks while not moving
>   the mouse.

Comment: This shouldn't be marked as the answer.  It's misleading as this isn't a bug in the framework, its working as designed.  kurrazyman's answer is right.

Comment: Sorry but hsCode and RichTurner have the right answer. ContextMenuOpening should be handled from ListView not from the ContextMenu itself.

Answer (score 53):

ContextMenuOpening event must be handled on an ancestor of the ContextMenu not on the ContextMenu itself. If you try handling it on the ContextMenu the event only fires when you right click once ContextMenu is already open.

Comment: Exactly. Right now you're trying to catch the opening of the context menu's context menu.

Answer (score 9):

I believe kurrazyman has the right answer, but it took me a while to understand it.
In my case I had a TreeView control with a context menu.
Using `myTreeView.ContextMenu.ContextMenuOpening` didn't work, but using `myTreeView.ContextMenuOpening` did.

Answer (score 9):

Its not a bug, it is working... here is the most common mistake that most people is doing with ContextMenuOpening event... consider this two different scenario to figure out the actual cause of this problem,

SCENARIO 1 (This will not work):

```
<ListBox Name="lb_sizes" Height="120">
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu ContextMenuOpening="My_ContextMenuOpening">
<MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
<MenuItem Header="Delete All"/>
</ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

SCENARIO 2 (This will work):

```
<ListBox Name="lb_sizes" Height="120" ContextMenuOpening="My_ContextMenuOpening">
<ListBox.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu>
<MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
<MenuItem Header="Delete All"/>
</ContextMenu>
</ListBox.ContextMenu>
</ListBox>
```

The only difference is assigning ContextMenuOpening event to proper element...
in scenario 1 it is assigned (attached) to `<ContextMenu>` element and in scenario 2, it is assigned to `<ListBox>` element which is proper way to do it and should work.

Comment: Oh got caught out on that one! You're right. I was using ContextMenuOpening on the ContextMenu itself, which is wrong. It should have been on the ListView in my case. This obviously also applies to code-behind (where you handle the event using Handles ListView.ContextMenuOpening). Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **IsVisibleChanged** event instead:

```
private void ContextMenu_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var isVisible = (bool)e.NewValue;
    if (isVisible)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to use the parent as mentioned in the *real* answer because my context menu resides in the `TaskbarIcon` control from Nuget; and it seems that, that control eats the other message.